# How to pause/stop random sounds (voice overs) in game using js or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, audio, pause

I'm building a game and I call the voice over with an if statement. My issue is I want the voice over sound to stop when the game is paused. voice overs are called using the audio tag in html and are played at random using JavaScript. Below are the codes:

HTML

```
<audio id="audio1"  preload="auto">
    <source src="sound1.wav"></source>
</audio>
<audio  id="audio2"  preload="auto">
    <source src="sound2.wav "></source>
</audio>
<audio  id="audio3"  preload="auto">
    <source src="sound3.wav"></source>
</audio>
<audio  id="audio4"  preload="auto">
    <source src="sound4.wav "></source>
</audio>
```

javascript for random playing:

```
if (Candy._score == 50) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
                $("audio").each(function(){
                        this.volume = 0.9;
                });
        var tid = setInterval(playIt, 5500);
        });

        function playIt() {
                var n = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4);
                $("#audio"+n).trigger('play');
};
```

the pause code

```
managePause: function () {
  this.game.paused = true; // pause the game
  var pausedText = this.add.text(100, 350, "Game paused!.\nTap anywhere to continue.", this._fontStyle); // Text to be shown when game is paused 
   //include voice over pause

  this.input.onDown.add(function () { // set event listener for the user's click/tap the screen
    pausedText.destroy(); // remove the pause text
    this.game.paused = false; // unpause the game
  }, this);
}
```

deleted the voice over since I didn't get the hang of it.

Comment: page has 404 error

Comment: Updated [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/pause)

Comment: code didn't change anything the sounds did not stop